# Angular.js - making function available in other controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular controller called SubmissionTreeController and it has update_dashboard() function which refreshes the ui every minute.

My goal is to refresh the ui on successful post request from a different controller.

How do I make this function available in other controllers?

```
var module = angular.module("submissionDashboard", ['ui.tree', 'ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap',]);

module.controller("SubmissionTreeController", ["$scope", "$http", "$modal", 
function($scope, $http, $modal) {
    $scope.selected_items = {};

    var update_dashboard = function() {
        var url = Django.url('submission:active_list_ajax', {
            site : site
        });

        $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
            $scope.list = data.results;
        });
    };

    update_dashboard();
    $scope.closeTask = function(scope) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'modal_close_submission_renderer.html',
            controller: 'ModalCloseSubmissionController',
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $scope.selected_items;
                }} 
        });
    };
}]);

module.controller('ModalCloseSubmissionController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', '$http', 'items',  function ($scope, $modalInstance, $http, items) {
    $scope.items = items;

    $scope.selected = {
        item: 1,
        text: ''
    };

    $scope.ok = function () {
        var val = $scope.selected.item;
        if (val === 1) {
            var url = Django.url('submission:close-notify', {
                site : site
            });
            $http.post(url, $scope.selected_items).success(function(data) {
                update_dashboard();
            });
        } else if (val === 2) {
            var url = Django.url('submission:close', {
                site : site
            });

            $http.post(url, $scope.selected_items).success(function(data) {
                update_dashboard();
            });
        } else if (val === 3) {
            var url = Django.url('submission:cancel', {
                site : site
            });

            $http.post(url, $scope.selected_items).success(function(data) {
                update_dashboard();
            });
        };

        $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

Edit:

What I am trying to do:

```
module.service('updateDashboardService', function($scope, $http){
    this.update_dashboard = function() {
        $scope = $scope; 
        var url = Django.url('submission:active_list_ajax', {
            site : site
        });

        $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
            $scope.list = data.results;
        });
    };
});

module.controller("SubmissionTreeController", ["$scope", "$http", "$modal", "updateDashboardService", function($scope, $http, $modal, updateDashboardService) {
    $scope.selected_items = {};

    updateDashboardService.update_dashboard();

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        $scope.$apply(updateDashboardService.update_dashboard($scope, $http));
    }, 1000 * 60);
```

What I am getting:
`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <-` updateDashboardService

Edit 2:

```
module.service('updateDashboardService', function($rootScope, $http){
    this.update_dashboard = function() {
        var url = Django.url('submission:active_list_ajax', {
            site : site
        });

        $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
            $rootScope.list = data.results;
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: create a factory method,so it can be used across controllers

Answer (score 2):

As @Gopesh says create a factory method, or, you can do something like this in SubmissionTreeController:

```
    $scope.$on("event:updateDashboard", function(){ update_dashboard() });
```

And in your other controller:

```
    $http.post(url, $scope.selected_items).success(function(data) {
        $scope.$emit("event:updateDashboard");
    });
```

Comment: Could you check at my code that I've provided? It does not seem to work

Comment: I've added a working example in my first post. I'll take a look into scope.emit because it might be way cleaner way in usage of functions in different parts of application.